# Java Program that reads survey results from a txt file and outputs the frequency of each survey answer

Tags: java

I have to code two programs. The first program outputs a survey where the user must input a rating between 1-5 (1 being a low grade and 5 being the highest) and then their name. The program then sends whatever the user typed to a txt file called responses.txt.

The second program (the one I'm having trouble with) is supposed to read the data from the text file then output a table that shows the frequency that each rating was typed. For example:

```
Rating Frequency
1      7
2      4
3      2
4      0
5      0
```

The way I set it up is I have 2 files, 1  java file that's supposed to do everything I mentioned above. The second java file is just used to test the program by calling all the methods from the fore mentioned first java file.
I have no problems compiling any of the files, so I'm good in terms of that.

However, when I try to run the test file, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.utiol.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at ReadResonseFile.readRecords(ReadResponseFile.java:43)
at ReadResponseFileTest.main(ReadResponseFileTest.java:8)
```

From what I can see, the problem seems to be with the readRecords method. My question is what can I do to fix this and if I'm leaving anything out that needs to be in the code, what is it? Any help would very much be appreciated!

Here's what I have so far

ReadResponseFile.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadResponseFile {
  private Scanner input;
  int[] frequency= new int[5];
  public void openFile()
{
  try {
    input = new Scanner(new File("responses.txt"));
  }//end try
  catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
    System.err.println("Error opening file.");
    System.exit(1);
  }//end catch

}//end method openFile

public void readRecords()
{
  SurveyResponseRecord record = new SurveyResponseRecord();

  System.out.printf("%-10s%-12s\n", "Rating", "Frequency");
  while (input.hasNext()) {
    record.setRating(input.nextInt());
    frequency[0] = 0;
    frequency[1] = 0;
    frequency[2] = 0;
    frequency[3] = 0;
    frequency[4] = 0;
    System.out.printf("%-10s\n", record.getRating());
  }//end while 
}//end method readRecords

public void closeFile()
{
  if (input != null)
    input.close();
}//end method closeFile


}//end class ReadResponseFile`
```

ReadResponseFileTest.java

```
 public class ReadResponseFileTest
{
public static void main( String[] args)
{
    ReadResponseFile application = new ReadResponseFile();

    application.openFile();
    application.readRecords();
    application.closeFile();

}//end main
}//end class ReadResponseFileTest
```

Comment: I have to take the garbage out, Oh do you have a question?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I forgot to clarify specifically what's giving me trouble. Sorry about that ^^'

The methods in this code (ReadResponseFile.java) get called from a file called ReadResponseFileTest. The problem is though that every time I try to run the program I get an error right where the readRecord() method gets declared. I know I'm supposed to increment the frequency for every number that's chosen but obviously there's something here that I'm not doing correctly. I'm not entirely sure how to approach it.

Answer (score -1):

For input values while executing your Java-programm, please use a GUI or use the System.in Scanner.

If you only want to read the TXT File, use a BufferedReader and read the File line by line by using

```
while((yourStringName=bufferedReader.readLine)!=null) {
System.out.println(yourStringName);
//What you wanna do
}
```